# Solving equation solution in R

Tags: r, solution, equations

I need R to give me this kind of non-numeric solution :

```
2*x = 2*y
solution { x = y }
```

Do you know if there are some packages who do that ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
> library(Ryacas)
> x <- Sym("x"); y <- Sym("y")
> Simplify(Solve(2*x == 2*y, x))
expression(list(x - y == 0))
```

Comment: Care to add an explanation of *why* op should try it, what's wrong with what they've got, etc.?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils good point in general, but here what Nane wrote is not even syntactically correct in R. Further, the `solution` function does not exist. I'm guessing the OP knew this and was just giving an example of what he/she wants, not asking why it does not work.